# $a_{n+1}$ = $\frac{1}{2} (a_n + \frac{2}{a_n})$ for n ≥1

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing

In this problem, we give an algorithm for computing $\sqrt{2}$. Let $a_1$ = 2, and define $a_{n+1}$ = $\frac{1}{2} (a_n + \frac{2}{a_n})$ for n ≥1.

> (a) Prove that $a_n^2$ ≥ 2 for all n. (Use proof by induction.)

Here I have:

Let $a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(a_{n}+\frac{2}{a_{n}})$ for all n ≥1.

Therefore, $a_{n+1-1} = \frac{1}{2}(a_{n-1}+\frac{2}{a_{n-1}}) = a_n.$

Therefore, $a_n^2 = (\frac{1}{2}(a_{n-1}+\frac{2}{a_{n-1}}))^2 = (\frac{1}{2}a_{n-1}+\frac{1}{a_{n-1}})^2 = \frac{1}{4}a_{n-1}^2 + \frac{a_{n-1}}{2a_{n-1}} + \frac{a_{n-1}}{2a_{n-1}} + \frac{1}{a_{n-1}^2} = \frac{a_{n-1}^4+4}{4a_{n-1}^2}+1$.

Additional Thoughts: if n≥1 for $a_{n+1}$ then n-1≥0 for $a_n$. Since $a_1$=2, then all $(n-1)^2$≥0, so $n^2-2n+1$≥0 = $n^2-2n$≥1 = $n(n-2)$≥1,  such that all n≥3 or n≥1.

I have no clue if this is how I should be approaching it or not, I just wanted to try something. Please let me know what I need to do for this and the following parts, such as hints! Thanks.

> (b) Use part (a) and equation (1) to prove that $a_n − a_{n+1}$ ≥ 0 for all n.

> (c) Conclude that the sequence $(a_n)$ converges.

> (d) Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \sqrt{2}$.

> (e) Modify the sequence $(a_n)$ so that it converges to $\sqrt{c}$. No formal proof is required
> for this part, but you should give a brief justification.

Comment: Why do you state $a_{n+1}=a_n$ after "Here I have:"?

Comment: Are you familiar with AM-GM inequality?

Comment: @rtybase We haven't learned it yet, no.

Comment: @Gary mistyped it in the wrong line. Should be all fixed now.

Comment: Your "Additional Thoughts" does not make any sense to me. It has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: It is easy to see that $a_n >0$ for all $n$. Thus $$
0 \le \left( {\sqrt {a_n }  - \sqrt {\frac{2}{{a_n }}} } \right)^2  = a_n  - 2\sqrt 2  + \frac{2}{{a_n }} \Leftrightarrow \sqrt 2  \le \frac{1}{2}\left( {a_n  + \frac{2}{{a_n }}} \right) = a_{n + 1}  \Leftrightarrow 2 \le a_{n + 1}^2 .
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of problem has been solved quite a few times on this site, but I want to try to show you how you could simply have followed the road map laid out in the statement of the problem.

In (a) you should at least try to follow the hint. Clearly $a_1^2=4\ge 2$, so you can immediately go on to the induction step: assume that $a_n^2\ge 2$, and try to use that to show that $a_{n+1}^2\ge 2$. There is only one reasonable way to approach this: start by expressing $a_{n+1}^2$ in terms of $a_n$.

$$\begin{align*}
a_{n+1}^2&=\frac14\left(a_n+\frac2{a_n}\right)^2\\
&=\frac14\left(a_n^2+4+\frac4{a_n^2}\right)\\
&=\frac{a_n^2}4+1+\frac1{a_n^2}\,.
\end{align*}$$

At this point you could try applying the induction hypothesis in a very straightforward way:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{a_n^2}4+1+\frac1{a_n^2}&\ge\frac24+1+\frac1{a_n^2}\\
&=\frac32+\frac1{a_n^2}
\end{align*}$$

Unfortunately, $\frac1{a_n^2}<\frac12$, so that doesn’t yield the desired result. We need to dig a little deeper. We’re assuming that $a_n^2\ge 0$, and we want to know that $a_{n+1}^2-2\ge 0$, so perhaps we should focus more narrowly on $a_n^2-2$ and $a_{n+1}^2-2$. Let $d=a_n^2-2$; then

$$\begin{align*}
a_{n+1}^2-2&=\frac{a_n^2}4+1+\frac1{a_n^2}-2\\
&=\frac{2+d}4-1+\frac1{2+d}\\
&=\frac{(2+d)^2-4(2+d)+4}{4(2+d)}\\
&=\frac{d^2}{4(2+d)}\\
&\ge 0\,,
\end{align*}$$

as desired.

In (b) there is also a very reasonable place to begin, even before you have any real idea of how to proceed. Clearly we want to look at $a_n-a_{n+1}$, and the equation defining the relationship between $a_{n+1}$ and $a_n$ is the obvious place to start: we’re given that $a_{n+1}=\frac12\left(a_n+\frac2{a_n}\right)$, we have $2a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac1{a_n}$, and therefore

$$a_n-a_{n+1}=a_{n+1}-\frac1{a_n}\,.$$

The hint indicates that (a) is useful, so what does it say about $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$? It says that $a_n^2\ge 2$ and $a_{n+1}^2\ge 2$, and since it’s clear (and easily proved by induction on $k$) that all of the numbers $a_k$ are positive, this means that $a_{n+1}\ge\sqrt2$ and $a_n\ge\sqrt2$. Finally, the fact that $a_n\ge\sqrt2$ implies that

$$\frac1{a_n}\le\frac1{\sqrt2}<\frac2{\sqrt2}=\sqrt2\,,$$

and we conclude that $a_n-a_{n+1}>0$ for all $n$.

Now (c) should be immediate: the sequence $\langle a_n:n\ge 1\rangle$ is monotone decreasing and bounded below, so … ?

(d) uses a standard trick that you can employ whenever you know that a sequence actually has a limit: if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=L$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}=L$ as well. Thus,

$$\begin{align*}
L&=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac12\left(a_n+\frac2{a_n}\right)\\
&=\frac12\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n+\frac2{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n}\right)\\
&=\frac12\left(L+\frac2L\right)\,,
\end{align*}$$

and you can now solve for $L$.

Finally, (e) just asks you to go back through the work done in (a)-(d) and see what has to be modified to make the sequence converge to $\sqrt{c}$ instead.

Comment: The induction hypothesis is $a^2_n \geq 2$ and not $a^2_n \geq 2^2$.

Comment: Sorry, but the second display is really wrong and should be fixed.

Comment: How do you go about proving it is monotonically decreasing and bounded in part c?

Comment: @Gary: You are of course right; that was an exceptionally bad mental hiccup. Fixed now, barring another hiccup.

Comment: @red: Part (b) is precisely that the sequence is monotone decreasing, and I proved in (b) that it’s bounded below by $\sqrt2$.

Comment: Ok! Also, how come we can't plug in the second $a_2^2$ on the rightside to be 2 in part a when doing the induction step?

Comment: @red: Because it isn’t true. In fact there is no $n$ such that $a_n^2=2$.

Answer (score 2):

Part (a) is actually very easy: the inequality $a_{n+1}^2\ge2$ is equivalent to
$$
\frac{1}{4}\Bigl(a_n^2+4+\frac{4}{a_n^2}\Bigr)\ge2
$$
that becomes $a_n^4+4a_n^2+4\ge8a_n^2$, hence
$$
a_n^4-4a_n^2+4\ge0
$$
which is true *for every* $a_n$. Since the base step is true, you're done.

Now you have to prove that $a_n>0$ for every $n$, which is also easy.

Next,
$$
a_n-a_{n+1}=a_n-\frac{1}{2}a_n-\frac{2}{a_n}=\frac{a_n^2-2}{2a_n}
$$
which is $\ge0$ because of part (a).

The rest is standard.